# Ordering sql query (not standard)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-order-by, case

I have a query that returns data grouped by time like the following:

[image]

I need to reorder starting on 13 and finishing at 12:30 like the following:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `hour` is of `time` datatype, you can do:

```
order by
    case when hour >= cast('13:00:00' as time) then 0 else 1 end,
    hour
```